# Why does not the session when you first launch the website?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-2

when you first start site does not work and the second session start okay .. site runs on codeigniter [armcars](http://armcars.net/) enter the site and click on the picture of the machine

index

```
public function index(){
$lang = $this->session->userdata('lang') == null?"russia":$this->session->userdata('lang');
$this->session->set_userdata('lang',$lang);
$this->lang->load($lang,$lang);
$this->load->model('main_model');
$this->load->view('main_view_index');
```

single

```
public function single($id){
$lang = $this->session->userdata('lang');
$this->lang->load($lang,$lang);
$this->load->model('main_model');
$data['query'] = $this->main_model->get($id);
$this->load->view('single_view');}
```

PS sorry for my bad english

Comment: headers already sent, maybe? turn on all the debug options: error_reporting, display_errors, and try again.

Comment: and you gave an error?

Answer (score 0):

If you have not placed anything in the session i.e. the first time a site runs for a users session, then there will be nothing for your code to find, so you have to test if the item exists and if not set a default.

Which appears to be what you are doing here in this line

```
$lang = $this->session->userdata('lang') == null ? "russia" : $this->session->userdata('lang');
```